# How does globbing work in Tcl?

Tags: tcl, glob

While using Tcl, as mentioned in the documentation [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl16a.html), shouldn't the following code,

```
string match h* match
```

, return **1** for the matched *h* character in "match" instead of what it actually returns , that is, **0** ?

Comment: Since you did not provide a *leading* wildcard for the glob pattern, your string must *begin* with an "h" to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same page itself you have the following content,

```
# Matches
string match f* foo

# Matches
string match f?? foo

# Doesn't match
string match f foo
```

The match is applied as if a whole word, not like string contains that particular word.

With `string match h* match`, it will try to match a pattern whose first letter is `h`  and further zero or more occurrence of any string of characters, which is not true for word `match`.

Instead, you can rely on `regexp` for what you expect to happen.

```
# Matches, will return 1
regexp h* match
```

Comment: That `regexp` answers a different question, and will match _any_ string at all. Well, as long as the string contains zero or more `h` characters, but that's every string ever…

Comment: Agreed. One query here. `regexp -inline h* match` returns empty string. Also, `regexp -inline h? match` yields the same result. That is fine. In both the cases, it is matching zero occurrence of the letter `h`. `*` is supposed to be greedy and why is it not matching the one occurrence of `h`?